# Position img at the bottom of its parent div without making any position absolute

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

How can I position an `<img>` element at the bottom of its parent `<div>` without using `position: absolute` or `position-absolute` class?

If I use absolute in any way, I break the whole design I have.

I also tried to add another `<div>` container for the image and a lot of attributes in different ways, like `vertical-align`, `bottom`, `margin-bottom`, etc. but no one worked.

The general purpose is to create a design like this:
[image: img in div]

but I have the problem I mentioned above.

I want those red images to:

- keep their original size (in px) for desktop devices (I don't want the small ones to get the height of the tallest one).
- position the read images at the bottom of those divs

Comment: Can you please share your code snippet so that, we can read and suggest changes according to that.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing it with the `display: flex;` property.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200" alt="" />
      </div>

    </body>
  </html>
```

CSS:

```
container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Check out [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-forest-rtr5y?file=/index.html) sandbox